# How to draw tubes around the edges of a three-dimensional object?

Tags: graphics3d

Suppose I have a three-dimensional object (such as a cylinder, or some finite parametric surface). Is there any easy way to draw tubes with given radius around the edges of the object (i.e., tubes which have the edges as guiding curves)?

Comment: Do you have the parametric equation of the edges,or do you want to "automagically" detect them? (The later is much more difficult!)

Comment: The latter, really. I already sort of guessed it wouldn't be easy, but you never know.

Comment: This is why it could be difficult, even for easy curves: The boundaries aren't just  the edges :`ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], 2 v}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1},  Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Black, 
 PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Transparent], Boxed -> False]`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't clever at all, basically because it doesn't "detect" the edges on its own, but I don't know of anything better:

```
f[u_, v_] := {Cos[u], Sin[u], v}; 
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
                   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> .2], 
 ParametricPlot3D[f[u, 1], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False,
                   Axes -> False] /. Line[x_] :> Tube[x, .08]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Pretty neat though. I could work with that. Thanks!